# How to exclude test files in next.js during build?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs, next.js

I am creating next.js app with tests inside the page directory.
For this I have added config to next.config.js

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'],
    styledComponents: true,
    i18n,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

All my pages have an extension page.tsx. For example Home.page.tsx. My test files are named as follows: Home.spec.tsx.

The problem is, my test files are still included in the build. I did exclude them in my tsconfig file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.spec.tsx"]
}
```

I'm not sure what else I should do

Comment: Can you share a bit more details. What is the structure of your pages directory?

Answer (score 10):

**Do not** put your test inside of the pages directory. If you do so, NextJS will consider this file to be a route of your application, and you will get an error like this when you try to build your app.

You can have your `.spec` files in any other folder such as `/components` but not `/pages`. As per [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#creating-your-tests), for testing pages you will need to create a `__test__` folder in the root.

Feel free afterwards to also update your exclude setting as:

```js
{
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Is this answer outdated ?

Answer (score 0):

Install `ignore-loader` (for webpack https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader)

`npm install --save-dev ignore-loader`

Update `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    // Exclude *.spec.ts(x) files from being compiled by Next.js
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.spec\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ignore-loader',
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Folder structure:

```
❯ tree pages
pages
├── _app.tsx
├── _document.tsx
├── about.spec.tsx
├── about.tsx
└── index.tsx
```